# SQL merge numerous rows into one single row using unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have data that looks like this in my table (users) As you can see user_id 9 has filled numerous rows down with certain metadata. This user has 39 different meta_values recorded against their user_id over 39 rows.

| user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | first_name | Gilda |
| 9 | last_name | Lilia |
| 9 | Email | test@test.com |

I really want to transform the data so the output looks like this.

| user_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | Gilda | Lilia |

and email, but I can't work out how to show it in the above table.

At this stage I have over 3600 unique users, and on average, there are about 40 rows per user. I want to be able to add different meta_values to the single row on and as needs basis, so really just looking for some help for the initial query.

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Would be a pivot. [See this](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78).

Comment: @PaulT. yes, that's it. However, I've just learned a new thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of me below query help you. here i have give table name as temp_user that you need to change.

```
select [user_id],first_name, last_name, Email
from
(
  select [user_id],meta_key, meta_value
  from temp_user
) d
pivot
(
  MAX(meta_value)
  for meta_key in (first_name, last_name , Email)
) piv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in your database add 4 rows (as you want here, you can create as many as you wants)

```
1st row usersID 
2nd row firstname
3rd row lastname
And 4th row called email
```

Come into your editor
Connect your database now insert value
Like this *INSERT INTO your table name(userId, firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (add values from your form HTML or PHP)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id,
       max(case when meta_key = 'first_name' then meta_value end)as first_name,
       max(case when meta_key = 'last_name' then meta_value end)as last_name,
       max(case when meta_key = 'email' then meta_value end)as email
from t
group by user_id;
```

If you want all 39 keys as columns, you would simply extend this to have 39 `max(case)` expressions.